# Facebook: Open graph actions not aggregating

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-opengraph

I am working on a facebook open graph application that will allow users who log in & authenticate with my site to have an aggregation of "recently read" articles on their facebook timeline.

I have created the aggregation and adding preview objects seems to work and it appears appropriately in the "timeline preview" area. Publishing the action works and it appears in the activity log (though not in the timeline unless I manually tell it to show up there).

Using facebooks url scraper, it appears that my links are working fine and all meta tags that are expected do indeed appear, but again - no aggregation.

I have posted probably 8 or 9 stories with my app so far and still, no aggregation.

Here is some code..

Facebook Log-In

```
$('.facebook-login').click(function() {
        var loginBool = $(this).hasClass('loginfb');

        if (!loginBool) {
            FB.logout(function(response){
                if (response.authResponse) {
                    updateStatus();
                }
            });
        }
        else if (loginBool) {
            FB.login(function(response){
                if (response.authResponse) {
                    updateStatus();
                }
            }, {scope: 'user_about_me,user_birthday,user_interests,user_likes,user_location,read_stream,email,publish_actions,publish_stream'});
        }
    });
```

FB.app share code

```
$('.read-action').click(function() {
    FB.api('/me/news.reads', 'post',{
        article : window.location.href
    }, function(response){ console.log(response)} );
});
```

Publishing an action logs the action ID the javascript console and like I said, it shows up in the activity log and I can see it on my timeline after allowing it to show up there.

The aggregation is set up as such:

Data to display: Read

Layout Display: List

Is there something I am doing patently wrong, or what are the steps needed to get my posts to aggregate?

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem with other build-in actions. It looks like custom aggregations aren't allowed for build-in action types. But build-in aggregations are sane enough.

Comment: This would make sense I guess except they still let you add the built-in actions as the "Data to Display" portion of the aggregation. Not only this, but even the built in aggregations do not appear unless I preview the app in "timeline view" and it just gives me 

<<User has read 9 articles>>

Answer (score 0):

What is the value of `Data to Display` in your aggregation?

Sometimes you need to do several OG actions of that type in order for the aggregation to start showing up on your timeline.

Comment: Using the built in action "Read"

It automagically adds a full list of aggregations corresponding to any built-in actions you add. I have "read" over 30 stories and they appear in my activity log - but they will not aggregate